# Device driver Node specific private data

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver, mknod

I want to store a specific data for each node (`/dev/foo[1-99]`) since I want to map each of these nodes to a specific HW.

I started with using `file->private_data` but each call to open sets it to `NULL`.

Is there something similar that can be persistent between `open()` calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is "No" (sort of), but you have misunderstood the usage of `file->private_data`. It is something you can set in your `open` file operation handler so that your other file operation handler functions can use it later. Your `open` file operation handler can use the device number in `inode->i_rdev` to decide which of your hardware devices is being opened, and set `file->private_data` to point to your private data structure for that device.

Note that `inode->i_rdev` is a combination of "major" and "minor" device numbers.  You can use either `MAJOR(inode->i_rdev)` or `imajor(inode)` to extract the major part, and either `MINOR(inode->i_rdev)` or `iminor(inode)` to extract the minor part.  This major/minor split may or may not be useful to you, depending on how you registered the devices. In any case, your driver will have registered a range of device numbers, and the `inode->i_rdev` value will be within that range.

The "(sort of)" in my first paragraph is because the range of `inode->i_rdev` values that your driver sees *is* persistent until it unregisters them (and then it will no longer see them!).